Do marriages have their own guardian angel?
Societies (churches, cities, nations) have guardian angels, but does every marriage or family have its own guardian angel? Marriages and families are societies, too.
Has any Catholic angelologist (Father or Doctor of the Church or prominent Catholic theologian) discussed this?

Just curious, where did you learn that "Societies have guardian angels"? I've never heard this before.

@CardinalSystem Churches do, because before Sunday High Mass the priest prays (after singing the Asperges me and sprinkling the congregation with holy water) the Exaudi nos to the church's guardian angel. Cities/nations do, too: Zach. 1:12, Dan. 10:13 (mentions "prince", archangels Sts. Gabriel & Michael) ff. (cf. Summa Theologica I q. 113 a. 8).

Wow, 3 votes to close for being opinion-based? How is my question soliciting opinion-based answers? There's got to be at least one angelogogist who's addressed this question.

How is a question asking for the opinions of an angelogogist opinion based? This site has questions asking about opinions from early church fathers and specific theologians. How is this any different?

@CardinalSystem Aparently Daniel 10:13 & Daniel 10:20-21 for nations (although it more an instance of an Angel fighting with a nation instead of the statement "each nation or a set of nations have a guardian angel), Revelation 1:20 for churches.

I like to comment also that have trouble combining the Idea of guardian Angels with God's omnipresence and Holy Spirit. Although I could see the point that God simply delegates the task of guarding.

Two sources of inspiration:
one,
two.

@telion Temporary glitch on the ChatGPT website. Both links work at this moment.

@MichalRyszardWojcik You're right, they work now

Do marriages have their own guardian angel?
The short answer seems to be no.

There is nothing in the Church’s tradition nor in the Scriptures that would indicate that.
The general tradition of the Church has been that every person has at least one guardian angel. Some have theorized that God might assign more than one guardian angel for specific individuals. However I am unaware of any tradition that would imply an additional guardian angel is provided upon ordination or marriage. - Do Priests and Married Couples Have an Extra Guardian Angel?

One could take the Archangel Raphael as a patron saint for those seeking to get married! At least St Raphael the Archangel has a biblical basis.

The Archangel Raphael is sent by God to heal Sarah, who, grieved by her trials and the insults of others, has begged God for death. And a unique trial it is: Sarah had been married seven times and seven times had seen her husband killed on their wedding night by a jealous demon.
Raphael persuades a young man named Tobiah to marry Sarah, assuring him that he will not be the demon's next victim. Tobiah follows Raphael's directions for driving the demon away, then he and Sarah pray together for God's mercy and deliverance. God hears them, and (to the relief of Sarah's father, who already had a grave dug for son-in-law number eight) they spend their wedding night in connubial bliss.
The author of this prayer must have figured that, if Raphael could help Sarah, he could help anyone. In this often lonely search, it's comforting to have a friend who can truly help us find a helpmate. St. Raphael is no Cupid, blindly shooting love darts with no regard for his victims.
Raphael is an archangel commissioned by God himself to lead us to the person God has chosen as our spouse from all eternity.
It's especially good to remember this when friends — bless their well-meaning hearts — try to help. Their favorite suggestion is that I move to a place with a bigger eligible bachelor pool. But I don't think moving is the answer: God knows very well where I am and where my man is. So, unless God tells me to move, it seems pointless to run about searching for a mate. I'm consoled, too, by Tobiah — he was simply running an errand for his father, but Raphael led him to Sarah. Being where God wants you to be, doing what He wants you to do, means you'll be ready for the spouse He has for you, whether you meet him or her tomorrow or in 10 or 20 years. - The Marriage Angel


In the strict sense, my answer would be no, the are no guardian angels guarding "marriage", per se.  ("Marriage", meaning the institution of marriage, which is an abstract concept, describing the relationship between 2 people, not a protectable entity like a human, or group of people)
There is Hebrews 1:14

Are they not all ministering spirits sent out to serve for the sake of those who are to inherit salvation?

But that is related to angels assigned to individuals, so one could conclude that a married couple would then have 2, based on this.
A weakness of this source regarding the tasks, purpose, and nature of angels is that the chapter is more concerned about Jesus and him being more important to angels. So this verse could also be interpreted as rhetorical focusing on angels being servants instead of the notion that each person has an assigned guardian angel. As you can see the sentence is phrased as a rhetorical question the reader/listener is supposed to answer with "No, they are." (It might be confusing but there is a Double negation: "Are they not ..." => you are supposed to agree with "...sent out to serve..." => but to agree you need to disagree with the "not" part => No, they are ...sent out to serve... => you are not supposed to say "Yes, they are not ...sent out to serve...")
Similarly, you could refer to Psalm 91:11-12:

For he will command his angels concerning you to guard you in all your ways.
12 On their hands they will bear you up, lest you strike your foot against a stone.

I am a bit careful with Psalms though, since they are meant to be songs and don't necessarily make statements that are meant to be generalized.
I didn't find any source in the Bible supporting the Hypothesis that there are Guardian Angels specifically for Marriages, but again I think the Bible could allow us to conclude that a married couple has 2, because each person gets one.
